# How to make Tomcat portable?

Tags: tomcat

There was a resource here:
http://www.javalobby.org/articles/tomcat2go/
but when trying to download the resource is no more available.

So how to make Tomcat portable ?

Comment: Here's how you can install a portable tomcat. Visit [http://tgducusin.blogspot.com/2011/12/portable-eclipse-with-java-jdk-tomcat.html](http://tgducusin.blogspot.com/2011/12/portable-eclipse-with-java-jdk-tomcat.html)

Answer (score 7):

If you are referring to the windows version, just download the 32-bit zip file from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) 
and run startup.bat. It should be portable enough, as it didn't require me to install any service / write to the registry. It does require one to set JAVA_HOME to a JDK (as far as I have heard, the JDK can be made portable as well).