# Portable JDK, Tomcat, and Eclipse (Windows)

Tags: windows, eclipse, tomcat, java

Does anybody know how to make a usb thumb drive with a JDK, Tomcat, and Eclipse (J2EE) (all for a Windows platform, preferably)?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843069/how-to-make-tomcat-portable), but the only answer was speculative.

I know that the eclipse part would be easy -- just put it on the thumb drive. Tomcat requires a JDK as far as I know. Would there be a way to setup tomcat so it always references a jdk on the thumb drive (rather than using the system JAVA_HOME variable)? How about Eclipse?

I'm thinking something like cygwin would clearly be overkill...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tomcat is pretty easy.

There is a standard batch file called `setenv.bat` in `<tomcat-dir>/bin` which is called by `catalina.bat` you could set this up to reference a relative path for the JDK.

An example of doing this is the [liferay](http://www.liferay.com) tomcat distrabution, have a look at it's `setenv.bat` file.

liferay 6.0.1 `setenv.bat` checks for a JRE installed in the `CATALINA_HOME` directory:

```
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%/jre1.5.0_22/win" (
    if not "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    set JAVA_HOME=
    )

    set "JRE_HOME=%CATALINA_HOME%/jre1.5.0_22/win"
)
```

Comment: Thanks for those tips! Any clue or leads on the JDK? I know eclipse can work with a JRE, and if Tomcat can as well I could use this: http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/java_portable

Comment: err.. just copy sun's jdk directory whole after  install there it can be copied and moved with out problems (except maybe for browser plugin's but there is unlikely to be your issue)

Answer (score 4):

I just saw this. It's 2012. Here's how I did it.
Visit http://tgducusin.blogspot.com/2011/12/portable-eclipse-with-java-jdk-tomcat.html

Comment: Please [provide context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) for the link you have provided.

Comment: Works great, Thomas!  I only needed eclipse+JDK so I ignored the other add-ons you had.  Thanks!